# Enforce a component to have only the properties declared on the prop types

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Is there a way to enforce a component to have only the properties declared on the prop types?

Suppose i have the following component and its prop types:

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const { name } = this.props;    
    return (
      <form>
        <input name="name" defaultValue={name}/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

MyForm.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Now, if i start to receive more props on the MyForm component and this props are not on the propTypes object i would like to receive warnings about it, is there a way to do that?

I'm asking this, because for me it would be amazing to make anything i want to my component and then later (when i'm done) just fix the prop types by looking at the warnings.

Comment: The behaviour you're looking for is exactly what proptypes does. You could also look into using Flux/Typescript if you want to typecheck your whole application, not just props.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/84 says to check [`prop-types-exact`](https://github.com/airbnb/prop-types-exact) package

Comment: Dragos Paul Marinescu - So, you are saying if i start to receive a prop called lastname on MyForm component and i start to use this property inside the render method would the prop type say to me that this property is not on the propTypes object?

Comment: skyboyer - Saved the day, thank you.